# JavaScript addEventListener for hidden elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce, visualforce

```
$('.inlineData :hidden').change(function(e) { });
```

Want javascript code for above..

I am trying like this

```
var aTags = document.getElementsByClassName("inlineData");
for (var i=0;i<aTags.length;i++){
      aTags[i].addEventListener("change", function() {
          console.log('anchor');
    });
}

<td class="inlineData">
   <apex:outputField value="{!objAccount.AccountType}">
        <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick" />
   </apex:outputField>
</td>
```

The above html code generates

```
<td class="inlineData">
   <span id="j_id0:frmId:j_id23:j_id24:j_id33:0:j_id37:0:j_id39">
   <div class="inlineEditDiv" id="j_id0_frmId_j_id23_j_id24_j_id33_0_j_id37_0_j_id39_ileinneredit" style="display: block;">
  <span>
   <select id="j_id0_frmId_j_id23_j_id24_j_id33_0_j_id37_0_j_id39">
      <option value="">--None--</option>
      <option value="Sales Prospect">Sales Prospect</option>
      <option value="NPD Customer">NPD Customer</option>
      <option value="Partner/Cooperator Prospect">Partner/Cooperator Prospect</option>
      <option value="Partner/Cooperator">Partner/Cooperator</option>
      <option value="Press">Press</option>
      <option value="Other">Other</option>
      <option value="Inactive">Inactive</option>
      <option value="Parent">Parent</option>
    </select>
  </span>
        <a class="inlineEditUndoLink" title="Undo" href="javascript:sfdcPage.getInlineEditData('j_id0_frmId_j_id23_j_id24_j_id33_0_j_id37_0_j_id39').resetFieldById('j_id0_frmId_j_id23_j_id24_j_id33_0_j_id37_0_j_id39');" style="display: inline;">
       <img width="16px" height="16px" src="/s.gif" alt="Undo" class="inlineEditUndo"></a>
   </div>
   </span>
 </td>
```

This is the code generates at page level. For different fields it generate different code. AccountType is a picklist so Its generate picklist. If field is text type field then instead of select list, It will generate input box

Comment: Use [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: What kind of elements are you targeting?  And, how are you expecting a "change" event to fire on hidden elements?  Please show us the HTML you are targeting?

Comment: var aTags = document.querySelectorAll("inlineData.hidden");
            for (var i=0;i<aTags.length;i++){
               aTags[i].addEventListener("change", function() {
                        console.log('anchor');
                });
            }

Comment: Hi @jfriend00 @rayon-dabre `<td class="inlineData">
                  <apex:outputField value="{!AccountWrapper.objAccount[field.FieldPath]}">
                      <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick" />
                  </apex:outputField>
              </td>`  Actually `apex:inlineEditSupport ` generate hidden elements. I want to bind  addEventListener fr those hidden elements

Comment: Multiline HTML or code is not very readable in comments.  Please add it to your question with the "edit" link.  And, please add the actual generated HTML (because that's what the Javascript sees), not your template file.  You can get the generated HTML from View/Source in the browser.